# create-react-app page gets distorted on refresh in production build

Tags: reactjs

I have built an SPA using create-react-app and styled components and deployed on netlify. My application works well in development but in production when I refresh any page or use browser back button, it loses all styles and in console displays "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Comment: Have you checked if any browser settings, plugins like adblockers, or dev tools might be disabling JS on that page?

Comment: It's the same browser I am using for development and production. In development everything works fine but in production build on live site at netlify it behaves differently

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.